# I need to get results from one minus another in range numbers with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Hi i need to make a code to get a results betwen two numbers. I have start number 1000. I want to get all numbers from 1000 - 500 in a desired range like I give in example.

I need one number minus another than minus one more time and loop this in range of numbers. Like I give you in example.

1000 - 10 = 990 Than I need number 990 - 40 = 950 and all that in loop till 500. I need to have code to do this.

```
1000, 990
950, 940
900, 890
850, 840
800, 790
750, 740
700, 690
650, 640
600, 590
550, 540
```

I tried with this

```
import math
x = 1000
y = 10
z = x-y
d = 40
print(x, z, sep=', ')
```

When I tried with range

```
for x in range(1000, 500, -40):
    print(x)
```

I get this

```
1000
960
920
880
840
800
760
720
680
640
600
560
520
```

I don't know how to mix this two and get what I need. Can someone to direct me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 1000
while n > 500:
    print(n, end=', ')
    n -= 10
    print(n)
    n -= 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function.

```
def generate_numbers(start, end):
    n = start
    yield n
    while True:
        for step in (10, 40):
            n -= step
            if n < end: return
            yield n
```

Usage:

```
for num in generate_numbers(1000, 500):
    print(num)
```

To make a list of the values, use `list` class.

```
list_nums = list(generate_numbers(1000, 50))
```